# Казаки́ и каза́ки

Tags: орфоэпия

Тут недавно задавался вопрос о происхождении слова "казак".
Я же хочу спросить об ударении. Один из отвечающих подчеркнул там ударение — *каза́ки*.
Но ведь есть даже песня: "Едут, едут по Берлину наши казаки́". Так как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Новом орфоэпическом словаре русского языка Т.Ф.Ивановой дается норма: *казакИ, казакОв, о казакАх*. (Но у Л. Толстого повесть "КазАки"; фильм "Кубанские казАки".)

Answer (score 2):

А у Ушакова - только казАки (30-40-е годы). У Аванесова оба варианта равноправны (70-80-е). То есть наблюдается движение нормы от казАки к казакИ. Поэтому у Толстого "КазАки". А в современном словаре казакИ. КазакИ, казакИ! Едут, едут По Берлину.
Наши казакИ (1945 год).

Answer (score 1):

Наши российские, донские КазакИ, а украинские, запорожские КазАки.

Comment: Данную трактовку только что услышал по нашему 1 каналу (1tv.ru) , так обосновал Дмитрий Дибров. Может Вы правы, утверждать не буду.

Answer (score 1):

Про **донских** не скажу, а вот **запорожские**, определённо, казакИ. С ударением на последний слог. В Запорожье говорят **так**. И на русском, и на украинском. Случись вам побывать в тех краях — будете выглядеть нелепо, говоря "казАки". Надо "казакИ".
А именно украинских, и запорожских в частности, казаков могут называть и через "о", окая. "КозакИ".

Comment: Да пускай они щоворят, как им вздумается. Казакам закон не писан.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то у Ефремовой ударение стоит так: каз***а***ки. При этом дается и вариант казак***и***.
Но при этом существует игра казак***и***-разбойники и мне сложно представить как ее можно произнести по-другому.

> А именно украинских, и запорожских в частности, казаков могут называть и через "о", окая. "КозакИ".

Ну, не очень удивлен. Было бы страннее, если бы О была ударная. Но по-немецки получается именно с О: [kosaken](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaken) ("козакен")

Comment: Потому что украинский не окает и не акает, а произносит так, как написано. А написано по-украински однозначно Козак.

Еней був парубок моторний 
I хлопець хоч куди козак, 
Удавсь на всеє зле проворний, 
Завзятiший од всiх бурлак.
©Котляревськiй

Answer (score 0):

КазакИ это те, что жили своими гуртами, со своим мироукладом, но боевые такие наемные петухи. Сейчас некоторые чуть ли не в национальность казачество возводят. казАки - регулярное чаще полицейское/карательное конное войско с шашками и кнутами (типа только кони-шашки и кнуты их и роднят с казакАми.

P. S. Это не энциклопедическое, точных прямо конкретных разграничений ни разу не встретила за все поиски, но это смысловое разговорное четко прослеживающееся. Не только на юге России, на Урале и в  Сибири тоже свои были казакИ, жили себе, служили кто себе, кто кому-то. А вот если где зарубили восстание, революционеров, рабочих - то непременно казАки.

Comment: +1, только не могли бы Вы использовать слово "нагайка" или "плетка" вместо "кнут"

Comment: А соблюдать орфографические правила вы считаете излишним?

Comment: О внесённой правке: если нейтрально говорить о событиях не удаётся (и Вы это чувствуете), то надо отказаться от их упоминания.

Answer (score 0):

Литературная русская норма - казАки. "Кубанские казАки" (фильм), Повесть Л.Н. Толстого "КазАки"... Моя бабушка и её родные сёстры и все наши родственники говорили: "Мы - кубанские казАки!, а когда я говорил"казакИ" - бабушка поправляла меня, говоря: "КазакИ-разбойники, а мы - казАки!" КазакИ - это украинская форма произношения, часто с заменой а, в первом случае, на о - "козакИ" потому, что у них буква "И" передаёт звук "Ы", а он всегда под ударением.

Comment: *звук "Ы", а он всегда под ударением* — Зачем же такие странные правила придумывать про украинский язык?